# Why post pages are on later list as compared to archived posts pages in Google search result?

Tags: seo, google-search, blog, site-search, search-results

I have a blog website [TechnoWide](http://technowide.net).

When I search on Google on how well site links are indexed in Google using search string

```
site:technowide.net
```

It shows the search result or URL indexed from my website.

But most of the URL in first 5-10 pages are from Category or Tag archived pages rather than the blog posts. Rather most blog posts are shown at the end of paged Google result.

Comment: It looks you are using wordpress and some setting missing for SEO. Which plugin you are using for SEO?

Comment: I am using "Yoast" SEO. But I don't think its due to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results in a `site:` are not guaranteed to be in any particular order. [This video from Google](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Qigo05nAqKw) states there are several potential metrics:

- page popularity
- PageRank (or something similar)
- URL length (with shorter URLs ranking higher)

And that video is from 3 years ago so there could be others.

It's most likely that because your site is not highly popular, URL length is playing a bigger factor here. The various tag pages are seen as the best "way into" your content. For example if you had 10 tags and 100 articles it makes more sense to list those tag pages than a random 10 articles because users can find what they're looking for quicker.

But it's not worth worrying about - not many users would know to look at a `site:` search anyway.